# Show ker$(\varphi)=\langle x^2-x\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have $\varphi : \mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}^2$ with $\varphi (f)=(f(0),f(1))$ being a ringhomomorphism. $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a ring equipped with the operations $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(a\cdot c,b\cdot d)$, with $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ being their respective neutral elements.

I want to first show that ker$(\varphi)\subseteq \langle x^2-x\rangle $. Doesn't every element in ker$(\varphi)$ have the form $f=f(2)x^2+f(3)x^3+\dots +f(n)x^n$? For the inclusion to hold, I would like to have no remainder after division of $f$ by $x^2-x$. But this is not true for $f=x^2$?

EDIT: I think I'm being confused by this part in my textbook: [image]

Comment: $f(0)=0$ tells you that $f(x)=xp(x)$. As $f(1)$ also vanishes, you get $f(x)=x(x-1)g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle x^2-x\rangle \subset \ker \varphi$ is obvious because $\varphi(x^2-x) = (0^2-0,1^2-1) = (0,0)$.

Conversely, $f \in  \ker \varphi$  means that $(f(0),f(1)) = (0,0)$, i.e. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$. Thus $f$ has zeros at $0$ and $1$. Zero at $0$ means that $f$ has the form $f(x) = f_0(x)\cdot (x-0)$. We have $f_0(1) = f(1) = 0$, thus $f_0(x) = f_1(x) \cdot (x-1)$. Therefore $f(x) = f_1(x)\cdot(x^2-x)$, i.e. $f \in \langle x^2-x\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the notation in my textbook confused me, since $f(n)$ also means the $n$'th coefficient in the $n$'th term of the polynomial $f$.